# Is it possible to add Rich Text to a Document Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rich-text, richhtmlfield

Is there any way to add a column that allows Rich Text to a Document Set?  I tried adding a new text column that allows Rich Text to my Document Set Content Type but any html tags are still being escaped.  But if I add the column in a regular list item content type it works as expected.  Any reason why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a rich text site column (I named it `testrichtext`) as below from

`https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx`

[image]

2) Now, go to your document library > settings > Click on your document set content type as below:

[image]

3) Now click on add from existing site or list columns. Add the `testrichtext` column.

[image]

4) Now create a new Document set and add your html description to it as below:

[image]

5) It could be possible that your html tags might be removed. But from the document set home page, click on edit properties and then the Rich text description will be displayed as below:

[image]

6) Now the home page is showing the correct html text.

[image]

Also have checked in the developer tools that it is indeed rich text.

[image]